# Hiding specific view in an activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, android-activity

i am making a kind of survey app . i want to hide specific views from the user till he clicks a button.

Can anybody tell me what to do ?

i would be grateful if anyone could help me on this.

Comment: On [Visibility attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility)

Comment: I have to ask you: Did you google it?

Comment: that was the first thing i did

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted or what you have looked into. Let us know that you put effort into figuring this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the status of the views programmatically.

You should use *view.setVisibility(View.GONE)* if you want to remove the view from the layout, and *view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)* if you want to hide it.

To put them back , use *view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)*.

Answer (score 0):

try using setVisibility(View.GONE) initially
and onClick use setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you just hide a view or set the alpha to 0 it can still be clicked on or touched. Best thing to do is probably to move it on and offscreen. Moving it offscreen:

```
    yourLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    yourLayoutParams.leftMargin = (int) screenWidth;
    yourLayoutParams.topMargin = (int) screenHeight;
    yourView.setLayoutParams(yourLayoutParams);
```